# Call existing trigger on Opportunity Update

Tags: visualforce, trigger

Probably an easy answer I cannot find.  I'm trying to call an existing trigger when the Opportunity Stage is set to 'Closed Won'.  Not sure how to execute it.  The existing trigger executes a Visualforce component.

```
trigger create_cc_project on Opportunity (after insert,after update)
 {
    if(Opportunity.stagename=='Closed Won')
 then(cc.ccUtility.asyncInitiateProject('Opportunity', Opportunity.Id));
    }
```

Comment: Triggers are not callable. They are executed automatically by the system. You can certainly call classes, such as service classes or trigger handler classes, from triggers. The code shown here is not valid Apex for a variety of reasons - if you're just getting started, the [Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers) module on Trailhead is highly recommended.

Comment: Triggers execute when DML occurs on the object; if you want reusable logic, move the logic in the trigger into a separate class.